# 2D space organic projection

Tags: math, glsl, processing, shader, projection

I'm currently working on a glsl shader (EDIT : I'm starting to think that a shader isn't necessarily the best solution and as I'm doing this in processing, I can consider a vectorial solution too) supposed to render something like this but filling the entire 2D space (or at least a larger surface):

[image: 1]

To do so, I want to map the repeating patterns on the general leaves shapes that you can see on the top of the sketch below.

My problem is this mapping part : is it possible to find a function that project XY coordinates on the screen to another position in such a way that I can map my patterns the way I want? The leaves must have some kind of UV coordinates inside them (to be able to apply the repeating pattern) and the transformation must be a [conformal map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_map) because otherwise, there would be some distortions in the pattern.

[image: 2]

I've tried several lines of thought but I haven't managed to get the final result :

---

**recursion :**

the idea is to first cut the plane in stripes, then cut the stripes in leaves shapes that touch the top and the bottom of the stripes (because that's easier) and finally recursively cut the leaves in halves until the result looks more random. as long as the borders of the stripe aren't on the screen, it shouldn't be too noticeable. The biggest difficulty here is to avoid the distortion.

---

**voronoi :**

it may be possible to find a distance function guided by a vector field such that the Voronoi diagram looks more like what I'm looking for. However I don't think it will be possible to have the UV mapping I want. If it's the case, a good approximation woult do the trick, the result doesn't need to be exact as long as it isn't too noticable.

---

**distortion :**

it could also be possible to find a more direct way to do this projection. While desperately looking for a solution, I came across the fact that a continuous complex function is a conform map but I haven't managed to go any further.

---

Finaly, there may be another solution I haven't thought about and I would be glad if someone gave me a complete solution or just a new idea I haven't tried yet.

Comment: The boundaries can be bezier curves, with matching end nodes. Where two curves comes together they can match in position and slope, but vary in curvature.

Comment: Thanks, I think i'll make a random leaf shape object and then split it recursively. It won't be infinite but it'll be enough. Now I have to find a way to create a leaf class with two borders, a function to split it and a system of coordinates inside the shape.

Comment: No code provided, but upvoted for the sketches.